# Compare only the times of two timestamps in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I need a way to determine if the current time is within the hours of operation of a certain model with an opens_at and closes_at timestamp. What would be a valid Postgres way of doing this.

For Sqlite3 I had:

```
                        (opens_at > closes_at AND
                        (TIME(opens_at) > :now OR :now < TIME(closes_at)))
                        OR
                        (closes_at > opens_at AND
                        (TIME(opens_at) < :now AND TIME(closes_at) > :now))
```

I forgot to mention this is running through `ActiveRecord` so `:now` is actually equal to the current UTC time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to cast the `timestamp`s to [`time`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE)s and use [`localtime`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

```
opens_at::time > localtime or localtime < closes_at::time
...
```

Rails will have everything in UTC inside the database (including the database connection) so you don't have to worry about time zone issues.

Comment: will casting to `time` ensure that only the time of day is accounted for, **not** the date as well. I don't care about the date, just the time.

Comment: From the fine manual: ["`time`: time of day (no date)"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE).

Comment: You crush it. Thanks!

Comment: @muistooshort This answer is fantastic! It helped me out as well. But unlike you said that I won't have problems with UTC this is the case. For me living at UTC+02:00 the following check is ony true when I define opening times substracted by 2 hours:
where("opens::time <= localtime").where("closes::time >= localtime").any?
Do you have an idea what to do so that my check works?

Comment: @MichaelL. What type is `opens`? What timezone is the database in?